# Integrating debounce to respond to a Formik field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, formik

My goal is that the user can type something in the input field of `websiteUrl`. Once he stopped typing the field iFrameUrl should be updated after 2 seconds and show the iFrame. However, once I start typing it seems to load right away.

```
const IntegrationWebsite = ({
  isShown,
  onClose,
  onSave,
  integration,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [iFrameUrl, setIFrameUrl] = useState();

  const handleWebsiteUrlChange = (event, setFieldValue) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setFieldValue("websiteUrl", event.target.value);
    const debouncedSave = debounce(() => setIFrameUrl(value), 1000);
    debouncedSave();
  };

  return (
    <SideSheet
      title="Add Website"
      isOpen={isShown}
      onClose={onClose}
      onSave={onSave}
      initialValues={{
        websiteUrl: integration?.properties.websiteUrl ?? "",
      }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      {...props}
    >
      {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid xs={12} item>
            <Field
              InputProps={{
                onChange: (event) =>
                  handleWebsiteUrlChange(event, setFieldValue),
              }}
              required
              name="websiteUrl"
              label="Website URL"
              component={TextField}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid xs={12} item>
            <iframe
              src={iFrameUrl}
              height="300"
              width="100%"
              title="Iframe Example"
            ></iframe>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      )}
    </SideSheet>
  );
};
export default IntegrationWebsite;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A debounced function, is a function with an internal timeout. Whenever you call the **same** function again, the timer is reset, and the countdown starts again. since you recreating the debounced function on every keystroke, the function is never called again, and the wrapped function is called.

```
const debouncedSave = debounce(() => setIFrameUrl(value), 1000);
```

To prevent this, you'll need to generate the debounced function once, and memoize it, so the same function would be used all the time.

To do that, extract the contents of the Formik wrapper to another component. Create a memoized debounced function, and call it from `handleWebsiteUrlChange`.

### Example (not tested):

```
const IntegrationField = ({ setFieldValue }) => {
  const [iFrameUrl, setIFrameUrl] = useState();
  
  const debouncedSave = useMemo(
    () => debounce(value => setIFrameUrl(value), 1000),
    []
  );
  
  const onChange = useCallback(event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setFieldValue("websiteUrl", value);
    debouncedSave(value);
  }, [setFieldValue]);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      <Grid xs={12} item>
        <Field
          InputProps={{ onChange }}
          required
          name="websiteUrl"
          label="Website URL"
          component={TextField}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid xs={12} item>
        <iframe
          src={iFrameUrl}
          height="300"
          width="100%"
          title="Iframe Example"
        ></iframe>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const IntegrationWebsite = ({
  isShown,
  onClose,
  onSave,
  integration,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <SideSheet
      title="Add Website"
      isOpen={isShown}
      onClose={onClose}
      onSave={onSave}
      initialValues={{
        websiteUrl: integration?.properties.websiteUrl ?? "",
      }}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      {...props}
    >
      {formik => (
        <IntegrationField {...formik} />
      )}
    </SideSheet>
  );
};
export default IntegrationWebsite;
```

Comment: Amazing @Ori, thank you. That works. Just one question regarding the `useCallback`. I understand we use `useMemo` so the denounce function is not reloaded on each rerender. But why did you add the `useCallback` here? Is it just for performance optimization or any other reason?

Comment: It's a general habit because of `useEffect` that might be triggered by the changing deps. Sometimes it helps performance by reducing renders as well. It's not really necessary for this case. Just a habit.